# cannot find symbol method swipe(int,int,int,int,int)

Tags: java, android, appium

i am performing a test using `appium` , i am trying to use `swipe()` function . but it keep on showing this error. it unable to read the function `Swipe(),` it shows `cannot resolve swipe`.

```
public class HorizontalTabscroll
{
    AppiumDriver driver;
    Dimension size; 
    @Before
    public void testCaseSetup()throws  Exception
    {

        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android device");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "4000");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "c://apks//seekbarsample.apk");
        cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

    }

    @Test
    public void testHorizontalScroll()throws Exception
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if (driver.findElement(By.name("tab8")).isDisplayed())
            {
                driver.findElement(By.name("tab8")).click();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                horizontalScroll();
            }

        }
    }
    public void horizontalScroll()
    {
        size=driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int x_start=(int)(size.width*0.60);
        int x_end=(int)(size.width*0.30);
        int y=130;
        driver.swipe(x_start,y,x_end,y,4000);
    }
    @After
    public void testCaseTearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

---

This is error i am getting:-- 
error: cannot find symbol method swipe(int,int,int,int,int)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Please post your code .

Comment: Swipe() is defined?

Comment: Try to edit your question like this : [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: WebElement contact=driver.findElement(By.xpath(                                  int wide  = contact.getSize().width;
        int hgt = contact.getSize().height;

        int startx = (int) (wide * (0.8));
        int endx = (int)(wide *(0.2));
        int starty =  hgt /2 ;
        int endy = hgt/2;

        //To move from Fav to all contacts, we need to swipe from right to left
        driver1.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, 1000);

        Thread.sleep(3000);

Comment: Error:(114, 16) error: cannot find symbol method swipe(int,int,int,int,int)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: where is the code for swipe function. Its probably taking 6 parameters and you are trying to call it with only 5.

Comment: i have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `swipe` method as it is marked [deprecated](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/ec9f586934b9c4931b43dd429b7aea1133d3a73b/README.md) and will be removed any time soon.
Instead you should use **TouchActions**:

```
Dimension screenSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
new TouchAction(driver)
  .press((int) (screenSize.width * 0.6), 130)
  .waitAction(500)
  .press((int) (screenSize.width * 0.3), 130)
  .release()
  .perform();
```

Comment: Awesome, please mark the answer as useful so other people knows it works

Comment: The method waitAction(WaitOptions) in the type TouchAction is not applicable for the arguments (int)  <--------getting this error for me